# Is dnsmasq a cache?

Tags: linux, cache, domain-name-system, dnsmasq

I have doubt whether dnsmasq is a DNS server or just a cache for DNS. I see in some of the linux machines that the dnsmasq is installed. Is it installed in default? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

dnsmasq is a DHCP server, and a caching DNS proxy.

It has *limited* support for serving local hostnames to local clients.  It is *not* a full blown DNS server.

Comment: Thanks for responding. Can we use 'named' as local DNS cache. Is there any difference between dnsmasq and named ? Thanks again.

Comment: The 'named' you mention is probably BIND (http://www.isc.org/software/bind) a fully-featured and most popular DNS server. You don't need most of its features, but if you want it to do the 'DNS cache' job, it will do it.
dnsmasq also responds to DNS queries, so it is a DNS server too, but a very limited one. It may be enough for your needs, though.